# How to create a measure without aggregation?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've two tables in my data model which are connected using DirectQuery. First I have a list of costs associated to accounts:

[image]

And second a list of groups of accounts. The same account can be in different groups and for some it's value may be negative:

[image]

So what I'd like here is to create a Measure/Calculated column that shows a summary of all the costs associated to a Group. The results would be these:

[image]

My first intuition was to write it like this:

```
CalcAmount = SUM(Continents[Multiplier]) * SUM(Costs[Amount])
```

However the result is not correct. For example for Group D, it first SUMS the multiplier 1 and the multiplier -1 and it results in 0. Then it multiplies 0 by the Amount and so the result is always 0 when the multipliers are +1 and -1.

How can I create a formula that doesn't aggregate the multipliers and instead multiplies each value individually?

Comment: What is your expected result? Note the visualization will summarize the group colomn so there will be only one row per group. So your first C value should be -160 and the second should be 160, if you sum -160 + 160 it will give you 0.

Comment: For instance group D contains accounts 1 and 2. If you see the Costs table, 1 = $110+$150 and 2 = $130+$160. Since account 1 has a negative multiplier it's -$260 + $290 = $30. I'll post a results table in the question.

Comment: What is the logic to determine the right `Amount` value for Group `A`, since that group corresponds to the Account `1` which has two `Amount` values in the `Costs` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

The measure you wrote is not correct because it does exactly as what you described: summing the `Multiplier` / `Amount` columns before multiplying. It should be something like the following instead:

```
CalcAmount = SUM(Groups[Multiplier] * Costs[Amount])
```

However, to make it work in Power BI, the following is needed:

- Correct relationship between the two tables
- Use the [SUMX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634959.aspx) function instead of SUM()

---

**How to make it work**

I suggest you to either group the `Costs` table by `Account` (or create a new table from the current one if you need to retain the raw data) so that you can establish a one-to-many relationship with the `Groups` table on the `Account` column.

`Costs` table:

[image: costs]

[image: relationship]

Afterwards you can create a measure and use the `SUMX()` function to perform row-wise evaluation:

```
CalcAmount = SUMX(Groups, Groups[Multiplier] * RELATED(Costs[Amount]))
```

The result will be as expected:

[image: result]

You can also add the `Account` column to check the details breakdown:

[image: breakdown]

---

**Edit: (Alternative solution by creating new table)**

Create an `Accounts` table with DISTINCT `Account` column only:
[image: accounts query]
[image: accounts]

Relationship among the tables:
[image: relationships]

Create a `Total Amount` measure which calculates total for each account:

```
Total Amount = SUM(Costs[Amount])
```

Use the measure instead of `Costs[Amount]` for the `CalcAmount` measure:

```
CalcAmount = SUMX(Groups, Groups[Multiplier] * [Total Amount])
```

Same result as above:

[image: final result]

Comment: Hi Foxan,  I cannot group the Costs table by Account as I have another columns in the table. What I did was add an Accounts table and make a many to one relatioship from the Costs table to it. Then I created a one to many relationship from the Accounts table to the Groups table. However when tried your formula the RELATED function returns "The column 'Costs[Amount]' either doesn't exist or doesn't have a relationship to any table available in the current context.". Is there a way to make it work when the two tables are related through an intermediate one?

Comment: @lisovaccaro You can add a total amount measure and replace the `Costs[Amount]` in the expression. Details please check the edited solution.